# Using memcached per user's querys

Tags: php, memcached

I am working on a web application and trying to understand how memcached works.

My question is about how to use memcached to get best results.

In the application, when each user logs in, a sql query checks 7-8 tables and get the results in an array. I was thinking to cache that arrays in memcached. But how should it work ?

Should i cache arrays per user with unique key in memcached ?

And how should i refresh that arrays ? with a cron job or what ?

thanks for your ideas in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the data should be cached by user with unique key depends if the data is unique for that user. And how should refresh the array depends on how the data is changed. So generally, your question is impossible to answer, and you need to read few tutorials before comming back with specific questions.

Assuming that you have function which output depends only on the arguments passed, you can create a key from those arguments (for example this is a function that gets user data and you are passing $userId - your key may be userdata/$userId), you can cache the return value of the function

```
function get_user_data($userId) {
    $cacheKey = 'userdata/' . $userId;
    $result = cache::instance()->get($cacheKey);
    if ($result == false) {
       // body of the function
       cache::instance()->set($cacheKey, $result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

As for invalidating, when some of the data has been changed, just delete the key from memcache